# Append a Unique ID to sprintf SQL query in R

Tags: r

I currently am running a loop to check if Certain ID's are contained in a function being called from SQL, but the function table doesn't have the unique ID column. I want to attach the unique ID to the output, before I rbind the lists together.
My code currently looks like this:

```
channel = RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("some connection")
output <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
unique_id <- df$col1[i]
query = sprintf("select * from table1('%s')",unique_id)

query = RODBC::sqlQuery(channel, query)
output[[i]] <- query
}

final_output <- do.call('rbind',output)
```

Comment: `output[[i]] <- list(query = query, id = i)`? Btw, you should have that inside your loop, I guess.

Comment: (After that edit...) If query is a table, how about `query$ID <- i`? Or maybe `output[[i]] <- cbind(ID = i, query)` if you want it as first column.

Comment: @Frank Hey thanks a lot for the reply, I appreciate it.  The way you recommended works.

Comment: Ok cool, there are other ways as well, covered in the link, like adding an id afterwards with `data.table::rbindlist(output, idcol="ID")`